Why can I not specify the key "guard" only in the \SetTblrInner command using tabularray?
My goal
I wanted to make a document with some bookkeeping tables.
I figured having automatic summing etc. would be nice, so I resorted to the use of the spreadtab package. For colored rows etc. I needed tabularray and for formatting of the numbers inside the table I needed the siunitx package.
Question
Why do I have to put row{1} = {guard}  in the specs of the table upon creation, and cannot only set it in the \SetTblrInner command? If I leave it out of the table specs, I get errors such as
! Argument of \__siunitx_table_print_format_auxi:w has an extra }.
! Paragraph ended before \__siunitx_table_print_format_auxi:w was complete.
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
MWE
\documentclass{article}

% Unrelated packages
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% Related packages
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{spreadtab}
\usepackage{tabularray}
    \UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}

% Setup of how numbers should be displayed
\sisetup{
    detect-weight=true,
    round-mode = places,
    round-precision = 2,
    round-pad = true
}

% Define command to display an amount
\newcommand{\EUR}[1]{%
    € \num{#1}%
}

% Define column type E to use in tables
% E[<width>]{<spacing>}
\NewColumnType{E}[2][1]{
    >{€\,}      % insert euro symbol before cell's element
    X[#1,       % column type that allows relative column widths
        r,      % always right horizontal alignment
        si = {  % use of siunitx library
            table-format = #2.2,            % spacing before and after decimal delimiter
            table-number-alignment = right, % horizontal alignment w.r.t. table
            table-space-text-pre = {€\,}    % make sure euro symbol is not part of spacing
                                            % TODO: why is the extra space not actually added for numbers
        }
    ]
}

\begin{document}

\section{Example}

\NewTblrEnviron{mytable}
\SetTblrInner[mytable]{
    row{1} = {
        guard,
        l, % left-align entire row
        font = \rmfamily\bfseries, % bold face
        bg = azure7, % blue background
        fg = white, % white foreground
        % TODO: how to remove euro symbol from first row?
    },
    row{Z} = {
        font = \rmfamily\bfseries % bold face
    }
}

\begin{center}
\begin{spreadtab}{{mytable}{
    width = 0.5\linewidth,
    colspec = {
        X[3]
        E[2]{1}
    },
}}
@ Items & @ Subtotal \\
@ Item 1 & 2 + 1/3 \\
@ Item 2 & 3 + 1/3 \\\hline
@ Total & sum(b2:b3) tag(total)
\end{spreadtab}
\STmakegtag{total}
\end{center}

The table shows \EUR{\STtag{total}} as the total.

\end{document}


I can not confirm that it works if you move the guard option. For me it always errors, and the problem seems to be the >{€\,} in the column definition. It compiles if I change that e.g. to >{€~}.

It also works if you use additional braces: >{{€\,}}.

or perhaps even three braces ...

Thanks @UlrikeFischer for your reply. It seems indeed that the use of >{€\,} causes the error messages in the log. In my MWE I ommitted the line row{1} = {guard} when creating the table at \begin{spreadtab}{{mytable}{}}, which, if inserted, prevents the error from happening. That's the reason I thought that the issue was with the guard key. Your solution seems to work (although I don't understand why). Any way I can accept it as an answer?

I asked Joseph about his opinion about my solution: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/66288877#66288877 He knows more about the parsing siunitx is doing there.

The placement of the guard option is not the problem. siunitx errors if you use >{€\,} on a header column. It seems to work if one adds lots of braces, but this probably fragile and relies on some internals. A safer version is to use something equivalent to \multicolumn to change the style of the header column or to avoid with other means that >{€\,} is used on the header column too.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
%errors:
%\begin{tabular}{>{€\,}S}
%{header}\\
%\end{tabular}

%errors:
%\begin{tabular}{>{{€\,}}S}
%{header}\\
%\end{tabular}

% works
\begin{tabular}{>{{{€\,}}}S}
{header}\\
\end{tabular}

% works
\begin{tabular}{>{€\,}S}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{€\,header}\\
123
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


Thanks! What about the >{€~} solution though? This one seems very clean, is there a reason it is not preferred?
